# Problem of continuous function

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity, self-learning

> Define the function $g(x) = x^2\cos\frac1x$ for $x\ne 0$. What should
>   be the value of $g(0)$ if $g(x)$ is a continuous function? Explain
>   your work and justify your answer.

Frankly, I have no idea what I should do. I need some advices, thanks.

Comment: Since you have a removable singularity at $0$ (this you have to check!) you can extend/complete the function to a well-defined continuous function on the whole set of real numbers...
"Engineerly speaking": compute $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}g(x):=y^*$ and (if this exists) set $g(0)=y^*$

Answer (score 3):

$|x^2\cdot cos\frac{1}{x}| \leq x^2$, thus by squeeze theorem, $g(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. So you need to have $g(0) = 0$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\cos \frac{1}{x}$ is bounded and $x^2$ tends to zero,
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} x^2 \cos \frac{1}{x}=0.
$$
So $g(0)$ must be $0$.